# wireshark - sniff traffic between two ups when using Paralleles desktop

Tags: wireshark

My Windows is running in a virtual machine using parallels. It is assigned to ip 192.168.0.116. My Mac is assigned to ip 192.168.0.129. If I use the filter

> http and ip.addr eq 192.168.0.116 the ping I send from 192.168.0.116 to 192.168.0.129 doesn't get shown, although it works.

What should I change, does using parallels require me to chose some specific interface. Windows is running using a bridged connection over Wi-Fi (not shared network).

DO you have any suggestions?

Comment: If the filter is `http and ip.addr eq 192.168.0.116`, the ping will not be visible, as it is not http. Try leaving only `ip.addr eq 192.168.0.116`